# Mapping : How to add a close button to infotemplate

Tags: javascript, html, esri, arcgis-js-api

How can I add a close button to the info template?

```
// My info template looks like this, 't' and 'Description' are variables

var infoTemplate1 = new esri.InfoTemplate(Title + ' - ' + t,"Description:" + "<br>" + Description);
```

Answer (score 0):

add:

```
<button dojoType='dijit.form.Button' onClick='javascript:window.close();''>Done</button>")
```

See this [link](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=158&f=2396&t=279947) for more info.

Good luck!!